# Number theory Question From RMO(2015) regarding fractional part function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

Show that there are infinitely many positive real numbers $a$ which are not integers such that $a(a-3\{a\})$ is an integer (here $\{a\}$ denotes the fractional part of $a$).

I tried putting $a = [a]+\{a\}$ which resulted in proving $([a]+\{a\})([a]-2\{a\})$ as an integer. Distributing, I got $[a]^2-[a]\{a\}-2\{a\}^2$ out of which $[a]^2$ is clearly an integer which implies $2\{a\}^2+[a]\{a\}$ is an integer. As $0<\{a\}<1$, we have $0<2\{a\}^2+[a]\{a\}<2+[a]$. I got stuck at this point and couldn't think of anything to do.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Within the questions body or in the comments? Sorry if i asked something obvious its my first time asking a question here.

Comment: In the question body

Comment: It seems clear to me if a number can be written as$ a= [a] + \{a\}$ with $ \{a\} = \frac{p}{3}$ , $0<p<3$ and $p$ integer then we see the statement is true

Comment: @wammysama in the question body. Also, try using MathJax to format your questions. By the way, welcome to MSE!

Comment: Assuming that $k \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, consider $a = 3k + \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @Buraian are you sure that's correct? taking p as 1 and $[a]=1$ doesn't give back an integer, it gives back $4/9$

Comment: @user2661923 if we take $k=1$ don't we get $70/9$ ?

Comment: @SayanDutta Thanks a lot for that and glad to be here!

Comment: @wammysama In my now deleted answer, I showed you can use your equation, assigned to a positive integer, call it $n$, as a quadratic in $\{a\}$. Using the quadratic formula, you can then determine all non-negative integers $[a]$, and positive integers $n$, which give $0 \lt \{a\} \lt 1$. The current answer to the duplicate question only shows there are infinitely many non-integral $a$ where $\{a\}$ is rational, but that is sufficient for proving the result.

Comment: @wammysama Good catch, arithmetic rusty.  How about $a = 2k + (3/2).$

Comment: @user2661923 yes that seems to give an integral solution for all $k \in \Bbb{Z^+}$

Comment: @JohnOmielan i was missing the step for after applying the quadratic formula and this cleared that up.